# Why is the listener not working?

Tags: javascript, extjs

Why is the first listener not working and the other one working?

How to set the first listener to work?

Maybe the problem is related to scope, this?

How can I set this to see the function available in MainControllers?

It is modern version `ExtJS 6.2`

**Structure folders:**

```
//FeedViewer
    //app
        //view
           //main
               /MainController.js
               /MainModel.js
              /FeedForm.js
             /Feeds.js
    //classic
    //modern
        //src
            //view
                //main
                    /Main.js
```

**MainController.js:**

```
Ext.define('FeedViewer.view.main.MainController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    alias: 'controller.main',

     onNewFeed: function () {
        alert('Hello');
    }
});
```

**Feeds.js:**

```
Ext.define('FeedViewer.view.main.Feeds', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Grid',

    xtype: 'feedslist',

    requires: [
        'ContactsApp.view.feeds.MainController',
        'ContactsApp.view.feeds.MainModel'
    ],

    viewModel: 'feeds',
    controller: 'feeds',

    columns: [{
        dataIndex: 'feed',
        text: 'feed'
    }],

    items: [{
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        docked: 'left',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'button'
            text: 'Add New Feed',
            iconCls: 'fa fa-plus',
            listeners: {
                click: 'onNewFeed' * * //It doesn't work**
            }
        }]
    }],
    listeners: {
        select: 'onNewFeed' * * //It  works**
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In modern toolkit `Ext.Button` click event is called `tap`. Also you can use `handler` config. Here's the [FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2jcj)